# C: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Tags: c

I'm typing a code with lists but I have a warning in the function **print_list**.
The compiler highlights the line 3 of print_array, i.e. **l=l->head->next**.
Someone can help me?

```
void print_list(list_struct* l){

    while(l!=NULL){
        printf("%s %s\n", l->head->content.name, l->head->content.surname);
        l=l->head->next;
    }
}
```

Following the definition of the structs:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
}t_contact;

typedef struct node_struct node_struct;
struct node_struct{
    t_contact content;
    node_struct* next;
    node_struct* prev;
};
typedef struct list_struct list_struct;
struct list_struct{
    node_struct* head;
    node_struct* tail;
    int count;
};
```

Comment: What is `list_struct`? What's the type of `l->head`?

Comment: Check if `l` and `l->head->next` are of the same type. Your problem is that `l` is a `list_struct*` while `l->head->next` is of type `node_struct*`.

Comment: @CoolGuy are l and l->head are of list_struct type and next is a field of node_struct type

Comment: ... which is why the compiler is emitting a warning, What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: @CoolGuy I know it, but how can I extract the next node after the first node, which is the head of the list?

Comment: The problem is what the error message says it is. You are assigning a value of type `node_struct *` (from `l->head->next`) to a variable of type `list_struct *`.

Comment: l->head is actually a node_struct type and also l->head->next is a node_struct type. whereas l is list_struct type

Comment: Maybe you want `l->head=l->head->next;`?

Comment: @CoolGuy that would also clear the list, probably not the desired functionality from a function called "print_list".

Comment: that would change the `l->head` instead try doing `list_struct* temp; temp = l` then do everything with `temp`

Comment: You have checked that `l != NULL` but forgotten to check `l->head != NULL`.

Comment: l->head = l->head->next doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Change your print function to:

```
void print_list(list_struct* l){
    node_struct* tempnode;
    tempnode = l->head;
    while(tempnode){
        printf("%s %s\n", tempnode->content.name, tempnode->content.surname);
        tempnode=tempnode->next;
    }
}
```

This will print your list and also not affect the head pointer of list, which you will accidentally change while trying to do `l = l->head->next`, which is also syntactically wrong, or while trying to do `l->head = l->head->next`.

Comment: With this change, if I input 3 contacts the procedure prints just one item, i.e. the head

Comment: @DanielaFavia are you sure that your `head->next != NULL`?

Comment: `void add_node(list_struct *l, node_struct* node_to_add{
           node_struct* nodo_before = node_to_add;

        if(l->count==0){
      l->count++;
  l->head=node_to_add;
      l->tail=node_to_add;
      node_to_add->next = NULL;
  node_to_add->prev = NULL;
      node_before=node_to_add;
     }else{ 
  l->count++;
      l->tail=node_before;
      node_before->next = node_to_add;
  node_to_add->next = NULL;
      node_to_add->prev = nodo_before;
      node_before = node_to_add;
     }
    }`

Comment: The procedure above is the procedure that adds a node to the list, i.e. links all the nodes...Maybe the problem is in here?

Comment: @DanielaFavia the way you were adding a node to your list was wrong. Have a look at http://ideone.com/e69g59

Comment: Thank you so much, now I realized my mistake!